# default of "calling" when run counsel-git-grep

Tags: ivy, counsel

`counsel-git-grep` is nice to search git repository, but by default it can't show the candidate lively. Meaning if I use down arrow to select the next candidate, the buffer doesn't change, and one solution is to use the `hydra` `C-o` and then press `C` to toggle "calling" from off to on. But looks like the default one is off, so every time I use this command, I have to do the same toggle again and again. Is there a way to set the default value of "calling" to on?

**Update**

Looks like the default value shouldn't change, otherwise other ivy commands don't work as well, so I am using

```el
(defun my-counsel-git-grep ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((ivy-calling t))
    (counsel-git-grep)))
```

Comment: For live updates I press `C-M-n` and `C-M-p` in place of `C-n` and `C-p`. The default bindings (and also `C-v`) are useful for making sure the correct file is found, instead of opening 100 random files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**N.B.** See [abo-abo's comment](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/33492/default-of-calling-when-run-counsel-git-grep#comment51857_33492) for the quickest and IMO best (most idiomatic) solution.

I believe the variable responsible for this behaviour of `counsel-git-grep` is `ivy-calling`, whose documentation states

```el
When non-nil, call the current action when ‘ivy--index’ changes.
```

So when the value of this variable is non-`nil`, moving to a different candidate in any `ivy`-based command will call the current action on the new candidate (in `counsel-git-grep`, this defaults to jumping to the location of the selected candidate).

You can enable this behaviour by default for all `ivy`-based commands with

```el
(setq-default ivy-calling t)
```

#### Update

As OP correctly points out, setting `ivy-calling` globally, as I previously proposed, will usually be unfavourable. Although (1) OP's custom command is a perfectly good solution, and (2) advising functions is discouraged where avoidable, my personal preference in this case would be the following advice:

```el
(defun my-counsel-git-grep--advice (grep &rest args)
  "Call `counsel-git-grep' with `ivy-calling' enabled."
  (let* ((sym 'ivy-calling)
         (def (default-value sym)))
    (unwind-protect
        (progn
          (set-default sym t)
          (apply grep args))
      (set-default sym def))))

(advice-add #'counsel-git-grep :around #'my-counsel-git-grep--advice)
```

Similarly in Emacs 25 or newer:

```el
(define-advice counsel-git-grep
    (:around (grep &rest args) my-turn-on-ivy-calling)
  "Temporarily enable `ivy-calling'."
  (let* ((sym 'ivy-calling)
         (def (default-value sym)))
    (unwind-protect
        (progn
          (set-default sym t)
          (apply grep args))
      (set-default sym def))))
```

The benefit of using advice over a custom function in this case is that `counsel-git-grep` gets to keep any optional arguments and its [`interactive` spec](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Using-Interactive.html) for free (i.e. without the user needing to maintain the custom function to match upstream).

Comment: Looks like ivy-calling is a global setting, and is it possible to only set it for counsel-git-grep? I checked the code of ivy-occur-next-line (or previous line), if we could get the the current command, then I might skip the calling of ivy-calling, some thing like   if current-command == counsel-git-grep or  ivy-calling ==t then call the action (I am not using elisp here). Is there any method to know the current calling command?

Comment: @DanielWu The current command, or "caller" in `ivy` terminology, can be determined via `(ivy-state-caller ivy-last)`. For example, you can check `(eq (ivy-state-caller ivy-last) 'counsel-git-grep)`. I don't think the `ivy-occur-*` commands are relevant in this case, however. If you really intend to check the current caller I think the function `ivy-set-index` is the place to do that.

Comment: @Basil I am using emacs 25.1 (spacemacs) After  I added your define-advice counsel-git-grep to .spacemacs, it doesn't work. Did you test it?

Comment: @DanielWu I thought I had, but I must have been mistaken. I'll see if I can come up with a workaround, though I've noted in my answer that abo-abo's approach is the correct one.

Comment: @DanielWu Should work now; the problem was that `ivy` would reset the buffer-local variable `ivy-calling` to `nil` internally after the `let`-binding in our advice.